# how to display the grid in div tag

Tags: asp.net, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var showGrid = function() {
      $("#Grid1").load('/friends/names/fried');
    };
</script>
<div>
    <%= Html.Trirand().JQGrid(Model.OrdersGrid, "JqGrid1")%>
</div>

<div>
</div>
```

I need to display the Grid1 here?
Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where?, It seems that you simply need to assign the attribute id to the div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var id_ind = 0;
    var showGrid = function(new_id) {

       if (new_id == undefined)
          new_id = (id_ind++);

      var grid = $("<div id=\"Grid"+new_id+"\"></div>");

      $(grid).load('/friends/names/fried');

      $("#containner").append(grid);
    };
</script>
<div>
    <%= Html.Trirand().JQGrid(Model.OrdersGrid, "JqGrid1")%>
</div>

<div id="containner"></div>
```

Comment: This ShowGrid i am assiging at serverside like this

grid.ClientSideEvetns.RowDoubleClick = "showGrid";

but this grid is exactly displaying on the other gird but I would like to dislay this on the other div tag.. 
thanks

Comment: Thanks, here i have a question..here I need to pass the string value with /friends/names/fried
I am passig like this.. /friends/names/fried + string
but on controler I am getting this string value as null allways..

thanks